# weird error with jquery sortable : is not a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-interface, jquery-ui-sortable

I am getting a weird error when i am using jqueryui sortable. 
It says,

```
$(this).sortable(); is not a function.
```

How to solve this?

**edit**
heres my header code:

```
<script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.sortable.js"></script>
```

and heres the code i am using to refresh my edit my xml file.

```
$("#sortable").sortable(
{
    update : function(event, ui) {
        //var change = $(this).sortable('toArray').toString();
        // $('#show').html(change); 
        var order = $(this).sortable('toArray');
        //var order = $(this).val;
    $("#show").load("update_engine_xml.jsp?order="+ order);
        //$("#showid").html(ui.item.context.id+" "+event.target.id);                                            
    }
});
```

EDIT: 2 
any suggestions why i am getting this error?!

Comment: It sounds like jQuery UI isn't loading somehow, but we'll need more information for a diagnosis.  Can you post the page's <head> and relevant JS code?

Comment: I got this error because, even though I updated my jQuery UI library to include sortable(), an old version was cached. I fixed it by changing <script src="jquery-ui.min.js"> to <script src="jquery-ui.min.js?v=1">. The number for v doesn't matter; it just tricks the browser into loading the new version.

Answer (score 8):

Are you missing a [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) reference?

Comment: I have downloaded the jquery ui in a js file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error and what I can see is that if the path or filename is wrong, the JavaScript is not loaded and you got pretty much no feedback on your end... only the loading returned a 404. You can see that in your Apache logs in general.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error.  I figured out that my jquery-ui-1.8.*.custom.min.js did not contain all the components this requires.  I downloaded it again with all the components and it started working.  You can download more components at http://jqueryui.com/download